# Calculate the euclidean distance via a functions with a variable parameter list

Tags: c++, c++11

This example shows how to use variadic templates to calculate the squared distance.
Unfortuanately, this will not work with sqrt() if I want to calculate the euclidean distance. 
How I can calculate the euclidean distance with a variable number of function parameters.

```
    /*
     * Calculated the euclidian distance of the obtained parameter list
     */
    template<class T>
    T squared_distance(const T &val) {
        static_assert(std::is_floating_point<T>::value || std::is_integral<T>::value, 
            "ERROR - squared_distance(): template parameter not of type integer or float\n");

        return std::pow(val, 2);
    }

    template<class T, class... Params> 
    T squared_distance(const T &first, const Params&... parameters) {
        return std::pow(first, 2) + squared_distance(parameters...);
    }
```

Comment: Do you have an example of the code you want to find the euclidean distance of? i.e. have you got some constant expressions? A std::vector? What?

Comment: `return sqrt(squared_distance(args...));` ?

Comment: Can't `std::is_arithmetic` replace `std::is_floating_point` and `std::is_integral`?

Comment: Each of the parameters is a distance along one axis, or how is this intended to be used?

Comment: This question could be interpreted in several ways... one of which is that you want "Params" to be a 2, 3 or 4 component (dimensional) vector and that's what you're templating.

Comment: I am just curious about the usecase, due to the fact that template are compile time objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code works just fine:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

/*
 * Calculated the euclidian distance of the obtained parameter list
*/
template<class T>
T squared_distance(const T &val) {
    static_assert(std::is_floating_point<T>::value || std::is_integral<T>::value,
                  "ERROR - squared_distance(): template parameter not of type integer or float\n");

    return std::pow(val, 2);
}

template<class T, class... Params>
T squared_distance(const T &first, const Params&... parameters) {
    return std::pow(first, 2) + squared_distance(parameters...);
}

template<class... Params>
double euclidian_distance(const Params&... parameters)
{
    return std::sqrt(squared_distance(parameters...));
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << euclidian_distance(1, 1, 1);
}
```

[<kbd>Live on Coliru</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c7c0147b91ad32a1)

BTW, you are computing the (squared) norm, not distance, as distance is (usually) difference in norm.

Comment: Not sure about return type of `euclidian_distance`, as with `{1, 1.f, 1.}`, result will be `1`. (Apply also to OP `square_distance`)

Comment: @Jarod42 Indeed, the type should probably be `double`. Although I don't know what OP had in mind. Will edit it as `double` makes much more sense.